# how to use services that are authorised with Azure AD with bearer tokens

Tags: botframework

I am trying to use a service that authorizes requests with Bearer token (Azure AD token) from within my bot.
How do I handle such a scenario.

Comment: We're working on a sample that will show how to do this properly. Can I ask if you're using the C# or Node.js version of the framework?

Comment: that would be really helpful. I am using C#. By when will the sample be available ?

Comment: @StevenIckman looking forward to it...could Azure AD be used to plugin authentication for normal users and not just office365 users? that'd save so much work. I'm thoroughly impressed by the work Microsoft has done in this space.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the strategy is to have a web page which supports your auth and send a link to the user.  When they click on it, they will go through the auth flow and when you get the access token you save it into the BotData for the user via api, and then post a new message back to the conversation.

After that, the bot has access to the access token stored in the botdata structure and can use that until it expires.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look to the [Facebook Auth sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot) to see an implementation of the Auth flow Tom is mentioning. For Azure AD, is pretty much the same. I posted some implementation details on [how to get Azure Active Directory B2C working with Bot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950160/how-to-get-azure-active-directory-b2c-working-with-bot-framework/37002612#37002612)

*Update*

There are two new samples that you might want to take a look since they are implementing the workflow being discussed.

- [GraphBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/develop/CSharp/Samples/GraphBot/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.GraphBot) from the BotBuilder repo.
- [AuthBot](https://github.com/matvelloso/AuthBot) from Mat Velloso

Comment: thanks for sharing this . I have already implemented my own OAuth flow, but would certainly explore these options too .